# Add values of a column of one table as columns to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am getting trouble in inserting values of a column from one table as columns in another table.
I am having **Table A** with some values in **col1** :
And another **Table B** with columns equal to values of **col1**.

[image]

I want to add rest of the values from **Table A**, **col1** as columns in **Table B**. Please help me out solving my problem. I am using SQL server 2012.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Please, formatted text - not images.

Comment: Show us the expected result - as well formatted text. And your current query attempt.

Comment: do you have only these values in col1 or you don't know all the values?

Comment: I am having other values too, but i have extracted the required values in table A , col 1 @rigerta

Comment: `SELECT Tag into #temp 
FROM T_UDA
WHERE UDACategory IN (
'Custom'
,'Description'
)
AND Tag NOT IN (
SELECT NAME
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.T_UDAData')

EXCEPT

SELECT TOP 4 NAME
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.T_UDAData')
)` 
from the above query I am getting non existing columns from one table T_UDA, now I need to insert the values as column in T_UDAData.

Comment: Give a Clear question with a clear sample data and you can get a clear sample result

Comment: I am having data extracted in temp table and these values are to be updated as columns in another table.
The query used to get the non existing values is :
`SELECT Tag into #temp FROM T_UDA WHERE UDACategory IN ( 'Custom' ,'Description' ) AND Tag NOT IN ( SELECT NAME FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.T_UDAData') EXCEPT SELECT TOP 4 NAME FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.T_UDAData') )`

I need a query that will update the values of temp table aas columns of another table. I hope its clear now. @reds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create table tableA
(
Col1 varchar(50)
)
Create table tableB
(
Col1 varchar(50)
)
Insert into tableA values ('abc')
Insert into tableA values ('bbb')
Insert into tableA values ('ddd')
Insert into tableA values ('Col2')
Insert into tableA values ('Col3')
go
Declare @colName varchar(5000), @Text varchar(5000)
if EXISTS (select 1 from sys.tables where object_id=OBJECT_ID('tableB'))
BEGIN
SELECT @colName=ISNULL(@colName,'')+ (Col1) + ' varchar(50), ' FROM tableA WHERE   Col1 not in (SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tableB'))
select @colName= SUBSTRING (@colName,0,LEN(@colName))
select @colName
SET @Text='ALTER table tableB Add '+@colName
END
ELSE
BEGIN
print 1
SELECT @colName=ISNULL(@colName,'')+ (Col1) + ' varchar(50), ' FROM tableA
group by Col1
select @colName= SUBSTRING (@colName,0,LEN(@colName))
select @colName
 SET @Text = 'CREATE TABLE tableB ( '+@colName+' )'
END
select @Text
EXEC (@Text)
select * from tableA
select * from tableB